# WebStorm TypeScript auto import with ~

Tags: typescript, webstorm

I use TypeScript in WebStorm and when I use auto imports it imports like this:

```
import User from 'models/user'
```

TypeScript does not find this file. In order to make it work it should be:

```
import User from '~/models/user'
```

Can I somehow tell WebStorm that it should use this format?

Another option would be if I could tell TS to accept 'models/user', but I don't want to add a path mapping for every possible root folder. Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*" : ["./*"],
    },
    "types": ["vue-router", "node"]
  }
}
```

I just realized that it also works with ~ when I remove the path mapping. So is ~ the default root symbol used by typescript? 
BTW I am using Webstorm on a Windows machine.

Comment: what is `~`? webpack alias? path mappings defined in tsconfig.json? Or? What do you mean saying that files are not found by Typescript - do you see errors in the editor, or problems when building your app?

Comment: What is the `models` library? If it's a directory it should be `./models` or something with a relative path. The `~` looks like the `typings` generated paths, which you shouldn't import directly, and seems odd since `model/user` sounds more like a user-written thing.

Comment: @lena yes ~ is the mapping to root defined in tsconfig.js. The error is:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'models/User'

Comment: I suppose some of the settings in Editor->Code Style->Typescript->imports should help

Comment: another possibility - maybe you should replace ~ with something else, because webstorm may treat ~ as linux home dir or something of that sort

Comment: path mappings in tsconfig.json are supported and work fine. What WebStorm version is it? also, please provide your tasconfig